# How to count the number of div and display nothing if less than some threshold

Tags: jquery

I want to modify the jquery slide and I want to count the number of div whose name is `ca-nav`.
If `ca-nav <= 5` hide this div (don't show) and stop playing slide.

**Note:** ca-nav is next and previous button.

Comment: Please post some HTML ,jquery code

Comment: var count = $("div[name='ca-nav']").length;

if(count <= 5){

 $("div[name='ca-nav']").hide();

}

I code like this it can count the amount of div but it cannot hide ca-nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.length` to count div in your html

```
  var n = $( "[name='ca-nav']" ).length;
alert(n);

if(n<=5)
{
   $( "[name='ca-nav']" ).hide();  

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JBYWa/2/

Answer (score 2):

```
var count = $("div[name='ca-nav']").length;

if(count <= 5){

 $("div[name='ca-nav']").hide();

}
```

Comment: it cannot hide now I try to .css("display", "none") it cannot hide too

Comment: @user3789357  .hide is working .why you are unable to hide.??check this http://jsfiddle.net/JBYWa/2/ & updated answer. .css("display", "none") this  also works.

Comment: or <div class="ca-nav"> is not show in HTML code but it show when I use firebug (Inspect Element)